# Ajax Contact form in MVC, issue with submitting the second time after failed validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have an issue whereby the AJAX contact form I have correctly reloads the first time I submit with the validation warnings, however if I then submit the form again without fixing the validation issues it loads purely the contact form partial view and nothing else.  If I remedy the validation issues and submit the form after one failed validation submit, it does send but the partial 'send' view that normally loads within the page loads by itself as its own page.

Here is my form (shortened):

```
@model international_mvc.Models.contactform

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/scripts/contactform.js")"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

<div id="form_container" class="highlight_box contact_box">

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("FormSubmit", "Home", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "cont_form"

    }, new { id = "cont_form" }))

    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form_col_l">

            <p class="form_title">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, "Name")@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, null, new { @class = "errortext" })
            </p>

            <div class="resize_input">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "First Name" } })
            </div>

  <div class="rcp_cont_right">
                    <p style="font-size:18px; color:red;">@ViewBag.Message</p>
                </div>
                <div class="buttoncontainer">         
                    <button class="button_form_send" name="btn" id="btn" type="submit">Send to OnLineTraining</button>
                    <button class="button_form_clear" type="reset">Clear form</button>
                </div> }
```

Here is the section of the controller which relates to the form submission:

```
public ActionResult sent()
        {

            return PartialView();
        }



        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> FormSubmit(contactform model)
        {

            var response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
            string secretKey = "akey";
            var client = new WebClient();
            var result = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", secretKey, response));
            var obj = JObject.Parse(result);
            var status = (bool)obj.SelectToken("success");
            ViewBag.Message = status ? "Google reCaptcha validation success" : "Please click on the recaptcha";


            if (ModelState.IsValid && status)

            {
                try
                {

                    var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
                    var message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("anemail"));
                    message.Subject = "Contact Us";
                    message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FirstName, model.LastName, model.Role, model.Location, model.Email, model.forg, model.orgname, model.COM, model.commissioninginfo, model.addinfo, model.phone);
                    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                        return PartialView("_sent", model);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return View("Error");
                }
            }

            else
            {
                return PartialView("_contactform", model);

            }



        }
```

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong, how can I get the form to continue returning the same partial view on the same page when the user fails to fill out the form correctly the first time?

I should probably mention the form above is part of another page which looks something like this:

```
 <h2>Contact us</h2>
 @Html.Partial("_contactform")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partial should not include the `Ajax.BeginForm` bit. The first time the page loads, the partial is included by Razor and sent as part of the complete HTML document to the browser. The browser parses this document and runs the JS that `Ajax.BeginForm` adds. However, when you submit, the partial is replaced via AJAX, and for security reasons JS in an AJAX response is *not* run. As a result, you basically end up with just a standard old non-AJAX form, so when you submit, it's handled like a standard old POST.

Long and short, don't replace the part that includes the JS that needs to run, namely by moving `Ajax.BeginForm` out of the partial that gets replaced.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks again.